# Visual Studio 2022 file-scoped namespace issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, global-namespace

So I have VS 2022 and am trying to learn C#.

I am getting an error of Feature

> 'file-scoped namespace' is not available in C# 7.3 Please use language
> 10.0 or greater.

I found where one goes to Options>Code Style> Text Editor and change to File-scoped.  Did that.

When I create my solution, I chose Blank Solution
I then added an empty project using .NET framework 4.8
Next I added a code file
Finally I add the following:

```
namespace Averages;

public static class TestClass
{
 
}
```

And I get the error.  What in the world am I missing?  I'm stumped.
Edit:  I just checked.  I have .NET 7.0

Comment: You're using the old .NET Framework, which only supports C# language version 7.3. If you want to use file-scoped namespaces, you need to use a version of .NET that supports C# language version 10. This means you need to use at least .NET version 6.0. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version).

Comment: I don't think this is a typo, for someone who is learning, confusing syntax from C# versions could be a problem, not a keyboard accident

Comment: If you are learning I strongly suggest using .NET 6.0 or later, not .NET Framework 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by:

```
namespace Averages 
{ 
   public static class TestClass
   {
 
   }
}
```

since Framework 4.8 doesn't allow File-scoped names, so the class should be "inside" the namespace.

But if you are learning, I would suggest don't use empty blank, syntax could be a bit different, but in learning mode this bit means a lot and you will found examples of code that often doesn't specify the syntax.

You could also try your code at Fiddle DOT NET https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks.  I am able to fix it with the solution you have in the code.  I was just trying to figure out why I can't get it to work.  I had conundrums.  LOl

Comment: I will wait a bit to see if someone has another idea.  I did upvote it though.  It does help.  I just can't figure out why it doesn't work.  I know I can use Fiddle DOT Net or Visual Studio Code or a multitude of other products it's just weird that this doesn't work for me.

Comment: I tried creating a Console App instead of an empty one.  Now it works.  I have NO idea what's different.  That did it .  Thanks Leandro.  I clicked yours as the answer.

Comment: @WinginSue thanks! My suggestion for the fiddle is that, meanwhile some code I use TDD to develop, I still use dot net fiddle to test some things that Im trying to learn.

Comment: @WinginSue for console apps you can found two things. First one and more evident, the selection of the framework (NET Framework or NET 6/7). From NET 6 or above, also you can check/uncheck "Do not use top-level statments". Since I'm old school, I check this one because I like everything, the namespace, the class, the whole thing. If do leave it, no namespace or class will appear and the code will "simplify" (not for me, at least)

Answer (score 5):

The reason you can't use this syntax is because you created your project using .NET Framework 4.8. This is the **old** version of .NET, which only supports C# language version 7.3.

See the image below -- the top one is for the newest .NET versions (5.0+), the bottom one is for the old .NET Framework (4.x and below). This applies to class libraries too.
[image]

File-scoped namespaces are a C#10 language feature, which are only available in .NET >= 6.0. That is why you can't use it in your .NET Framework 4.8 project.

You would need to create a project that supports the newer .NET versions, ***not .NET Framework***, if you want to use the latest C# language features.

[This Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) describes the relationship between C#/.NET versions.